# How to connect excel to a MySQL database

Tags: database, excel, database-connection

I have a database in MySQL and need work with some info in excel but I don't know how to connected

Comment: to conect to mysql by excel. [link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/connect-to-a-mysql-database-power-query-8760c647-88b9-409d-b312-6ea8f84a269b). but what you really want to do? you can use macros then use vbs to conect to mysql by code. but tell me what is your target?